# Uncountable choice set

Tags: measure-theory

I read that a choice set for the rational equivalence relation on a set whose outer measure is positive must necessarily be uncountable. I am having trouble seeing why this is true and was hoping someone could explain this to me. I thought that it would have to have the same cardinality as $\mathbb{Q}$, which is countable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rational Equivalence Relation and Measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3830165/rational-equivalence-relation-and-measure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Countable sets are of measure zero, therefore they have outer measure zero. Therefore if a set has a positive outer measure, it cannot be countable.

Note that while each equivalence class of $\Bbb{R/Q}$ is countable, there are uncountably many of these classes. Therefore a set choosing a point from each equivalence class must be uncountable.

Comment: The question deals with any set with positive outer measure, but you jump to $\mathbb R$.  How do you justify that?

Comment: Because any set with a positive outer measure has to be uncountable. It's an illustrative example.