# Rational Equivalence Relation and Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Here is the problem and my attempted solution.

**Problem:** Let $m^*(E) > 0$. Define the Rational Equivalence Relation on $E$ by $x \sim y$ if, any only if, $x - y \in \mathbb{Q}$. Show that the choice set $(c_E)$ for the Rational Equivalence Relation must be uncountably infinite.

(my) **Solution:** Let $m^*(E) > 0$. Define the Rational Equivalence Relation on $E$ by $x \sim y$ if, any only if, $x - y \in \mathbb{Q}$. By way of contradiction, suppose that $c_E$ is countably infinite. Notice, one property of $c_E$ is the following:

(i) For any $e \in E, \exists c \in c_E: e - c = q$, for $q \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Therefore, by (i) if $c_E$ is countably infinite so is $E$. Since the Lebesgue Outer Measure of a countably infinite set is zero we obtain:
$$m^*(E) = 0,$$
a contradiction. Hence, our assumption that $c_E$ is countably infinite is false. Therefore, $c_E$ must be uncountably infinite, as desired.

Comment: Your solution seems correct.

Comment: You could make your solution maybe slightly clearer: 

Let $m^*(E) > 0$. Define the Rational Equivalence Relation on $E$ by $x \sim y$ if, any only if, $x - y \in \mathbb{Q}$. By way of contradiction, suppose that $c_E$ is countably infinite. Notice, one property of $c_E$ is the following:

$$E \subseteq \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}}(c_E+q) $$ 

Therefore, if $c_E$ is countable so is $E$. Since the Lebesgue Outer Measure of a countable set is zero we obtain: 
$$m^*(E) = 0,$$
a contradiction.

Comment: @Ramiro That is more clear, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct. You could make your solution maybe slightly clearer:

Let $m^*(E) > 0$. Define the Rational Equivalence Relation on $E$ by $x \sim y$ if, any only if, $x - y \in \mathbb{Q}$. By way of contradiction, suppose that $c_E$ is countably infinite. Notice, one property of $c_E$ is the following:

$$E \subseteq \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}}(c_E+q) $$

Therefore, if $c_E$ is countable so is $E$. Since the Lebesgue Outer Measure of a countable set is zero we obtain:
$$m^*(E) = 0,$$
a contradiction.